# Keycloak - Assign User to group from registration form

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to create a custom registration form in Keycloak that will create the user and assign them to a group depending on a team drop down selection. Here is an example of my problem:

I have multiple teams that will be using keycloak and each team will have their own group in keycloak mapping out all the roles that they need access to. One app that will be using keycloak authentication is Grafana. When a user goes to Grafana and tries to register for a new account via keycloak, it creates the user, but because the user isn't assigned to a group, they land at an error page in Grafana because they don't have any privilege. 

I'm trying to limit the amount of manual work to assign hundreds of users to groups after they register. I don't have access to LDAP or Active Directroy. 

Here is an example of what i've tried in my custom register.ftl template.

```
        <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!} ${messagesPerField.printIfExists('team',properties.kcFormGroupErrorClass!)}">
            <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
                <label for="groups" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">Team</label>
            </div>

            <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
                <select class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" id="groups" name="groups" value="${(register.formData['groups']!'')}">
                    <option value="group1">Group 1</option>
                    <option value="group2">Group 2</option>
                    <option value="group3">Group 3</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I was successfully able to add the group as a user attribute, and then thought I could execute a script after that uses the rest API to then assign the group, but I haven't had much luck with that either. I would like to stay away from assigning everyone to a default "view only" group because some groups don't need to be able to view all the apps that we will use.

If anyone has any ideas or could help point me in the right direction, please let me know. I have limited knowledge HTML & Javascript but know my way around Python.

Comment: Do you use any backend server or are you doing the whole stuff in javascript? As far as I can read, you want the new users to be added to KC groups. Do you create the users yourself from JS? The proper way would be, set up a Python backend and give it a client ID, which can create new users and assign user groups. The python server will have the ability to create users and assign them groups, NOT the front-end code. The front end code will just communicate with your Python server in order to create new users, without knowing what's going under the covers.

Comment: I'm creating the new users via the registration form. New users can click the "new user" button and it brings them to the keycloak registration page where they fill in account info and press submit. Keycloak does the rest. (I'm basically extending the default registration form) I do really like your idea however. I do have a script that can add a user to a group. I may be able to elaborate on that some more and build a flask or django web server that could be called when the user presses the submit button instead of having KC handle the creation. I think that's what you were talking about.

Comment: Exactly, you would have your Django application as a keycloak client with user creation and role assignation permissions, so as when a new application user is created, Django would manage the creation and have the permissions to do it via the KC API. Another workaround is to keep KC managing the user creation and create your own Event Listener SPI, if user creation happens to be an event (I'm not sure about it): https://dev.to/adwaitthattey/building-an-event-listener-spi-plugin-for-keycloak-2044